# nvim-treesitter not working; throws error E5113

Tags: vimscript, neovim, plugin-treesitter

I just installed `nvim-treesitter` and it throws me this error message when starting nvim:

```
Error detected while processing /home/MYUSERNAME/.local/share/nvim/plugged/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .../nvim/plugged/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua:14: attempt to call field 'nvim_create_augroup' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        .../nvim/plugged/nvim-treesitter/plugin/nvim-treesitter.lua:14: in main chunk
```

Here's my installation line:

```
Plug 'https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}
```

What can I do?

Comment: I would strongly recommend reporting a bug on the project repo; they are more likely to have the insight required to solve the problem.